# How can I print the Joystick click to the console via the JInput library?

Tags: java, joystick, jinput

I am working on Java map project. I use the Logitech extreme 3D pro Joystick and *JInput* library. I want to write text to the console when the buttons on the joystick are clicked. But I can't do that, can anyone help?

Comment: Please consider adding what you have already tried / your research to your question. Have you looked at the API's? Do you need help with choosing one of a handful of API calls? The more specific you are the more likely you are to get answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt the *[JInput](https://github.com/jinput/jinput)* example found [here](https://github.com/jinput/jinput/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/net/java/games/input/example/ReadFirstMouse.java) which shows "how to read the values in a polling loop for the first mouse". In line 28 simply change the controller type to  **`STICK`**, as it is defined in the [`Controller`](https://github.com/jinput/jinput/blob/master/coreAPI/src/main/java/net/java/games/input/Controller.java) class of that library:

```
/**
 * Stick controller, such as a joystick or flightstick.
 */
public static final Type STICK = new Type("Stick");
```

If you execute the example you will retrieve "the components of the controller" (see line 46, `/* Get all the axis and buttons */`).

With those components at hand, you can retrieve properties or data from the connected (joystick) controller, in your case not a mouse but a joystick.

Hint: Before modifying the example, you can just start to experiment with the "first mouse" connected to your machine.